# My deployed app closes immediately on jailbroken iPhone, already code signed

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, jailbreak

I'm creating an app to run on my jailbroken iPhone 5 that's running iOS 6.1.2 jailbroken using evasi0n.

I followed this guide http://www.sysrage.net/guides/ios-programming/building-and-running-ios-applications-without-a-paid-developer-license to no avail.

These are the steps I took:

- I am using Xcode 4.6.2, have git installed, have ldid installed according to the instructions.
- I configured Xcode to not code sign.
- Run "Build", which is set to build for iOS device.
- Used ldid -S on the app that was created from the previous step. ldid completed without any errors.
- Then, I connected my phone via USB and used iFunBox to transfer my code signed app into /Applications/
- On my phone, I installed MobileTerminal, so I open that up and run `uicache`, which rebuilds the UI cache. Then I run `killall backboardd`, which is equivalent to doing a respring using Springboard.

My app appears on my phone, which is good. But, when I tap it to open, it immediately closes. I don't understand why this is happening. I've done the fake code signing using ldid.